# "Let’s try them in a sentence" vs. "Let’s try them in some sentences"

Tags: singular-vs-plural

[A tutorial](https://youtu.be/nbnRm_3_QKU?list=PLD6t6ckHsrubLp8Ia8duzu5fN4riM2-Bl&t=309) introduces some rules about pronunciation

> when one word ends with a consonant sound, and the next word starts
> with the same consonant sound, we link the sounds.

And then some exceptions are introduced

> But, there are two exceptions to this rule: we don’t link /tʃ/ or /dʒ/ sounds ...

to given some examples to practice, the speaker says

> Let’s try them in **a sentence**

Using "them" to refer to "two exceptions" is reasonable. However, she gives **two sentences** after then.

Should she say the following?

> Let’s try them in **some sentences**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Let’s try them in a sentence
```

Would mean a singular sentence.

```
Let’s try them in some sentences
```

Would mean multiple sentences.

So yes, she should have said the *some sentences.*